# when to call XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Is there a difference in browser behavior between:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',url);
xhr.onload = function(){/*various things*/};
xhr.onerror = function(){/*various things*/};
xhr.send();
```

and

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){/*various things*/};
xhr.onerror = function(){/*various things*/};
xhr.open('GET',url);    
xhr.send();
```

The reason I ask: I have an uploading process that performs ~500 xhr.sends() (over many GBs of uploads), and I'm seeing that sometimes just one of the .sends() silently fails - no evidence of the request in the servers logs, and no errors shown on the client side. As an experiment I changed my code from the 1st pattern above, to the 2nd pattern, and it *seems* to be 'fixed', but n=1 does not a proof make, so I'm trying to figure whether there is a best practice, or rationale for doing #2 instead of #1.

It's in Chrome 25.0.1364.172m on Win7. Perhaps it's a Chrome bug, but before I file that I want to check I'm not missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you've shown behaves identical in all respects.

Comment: Are you doing these xhr requests all at the same time? Or waiting till one finishes to trigger another? If you create a massive bottleneck of 500 xhr's at the same time then yeah, you might be breaking the browser.

Comment: You said you are performing this like 500 times. All with the same variable name? If you are doing concurrent requests it will cause issues. Overwriting an object reference will get it destroyed by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Havenard In fact, isn't it the same with one request ? You usually don't keep a reference to it, you just send it and let the browser call the callbacks.

Comment: Its most certain there is a limit for how many concurrent XMLHttpRequest you can have open aswell.

Comment: The spec says that active XHRs should not be garbage collected, so the overwritten reference shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: A problem of dropped requests might also be server side. How is the server implemented ?

Comment: @Havenard Where do you see things being overwritten?

Comment: @Ian he said he is calling `xhr.send()` ~500 times. It implies he is using the same variable name.

Comment: @Havenard It also implies this code is in a function that is being reused. And the fact that they're using `var` means they are creating a completely new object for each function call. If `xhr` were global, then maybe this would be a problem. But it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Ian - you are correct, it's in a function, so the scope is separate for each call. The requests are not all concurrent - it's currently capped at 5 concurrent. Since writing this question I've discovered that the underlying problem is probably something else - the file the user was attempting to upload had only been partially downloaded, so was quite possibly corrupted. The xhr.send was failing right around the byte range of the truncated file size. So that's probably the root cause, though it's not clear why it causes send() to fail, nor silently. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob W stated "The code you've shown behaves identical in all respects.". No-one contested that, and I have no evidence to the contrary, so I'm accepting that as the answer. Thanks Rob.